# Trying to set up email using php postfix on mac

Tags: php, macos, email, postfix-mta

Hi i have a simple contact form in php which lets a user send feedback and should send me this in an email.

I have followed a few tutorials in setting up Postfix and can successfully send an email using the terminal however i want to send the email from my php page.

Im really confused of what step to follow next. what do i need to do to be able to achieve this? i have looked on tutorials and they just show how i can send an email through terminal but really i want to be able to send it through the php page but not sure who to do this.

Overwhelmed with the amount of information online. Can anyone help me with this process please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a simple addition to the php ini file. Needed to just specify the localhost port for SMTP and the gmail STMP server. Then just needed to turn on the postfix system via the terminal. Hope this helps anyone else who has been struggling with this!

Comment: follow the instruction using this article, just need to setup couple entry.
https://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-emails-from-localhost-mac-os-x-el-capitan/